# MS Office - Embedding Video using new office JavaScript based API

Tags: c#, ms-office, office365, office-addins, office-js

I developed one plugin with office VSTO for MS Word using which I was able to embed a Video into word document using following code.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddWebVideo(@"<iframe width='400' height='400' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/qk51u8-4uo4' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen />"
, VideoWidth: 400
, VideoHeight: 400
, PosterFrameImage: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qk51u8-4uo4/hqdefault.jpg"
, Range: currentRange);
```

Now, I'm developing another add-in using JavaScript based API based on API reference here at:

[Add-In APIs - Javascript Office 365/2016](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-and-debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio?product=word)

My question is, I was not able to find any relative API for embedding a video into word document.

Please help me in identifying the right API?

If that's limitation, Can I add some `text/XML/picture` in the document, add binding to it and then when user clicks on that `text/XML/picture`, the video will be played in Add-In itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time we don't have an API to insert a video specifically, but you can insert rich content into Word using OOXML.
Here's an overview: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml

Here's the new Api and usage of how to insert it:
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body#insertooxmlooxml-string-insertlocation-insertlocation

Comment: Does that mean that, By direct mean there are no APIs...but one can add video using open office XML (I'm not good at this, sorry if this seems a silly question)?

Comment: @HirenDesai yes there is no API specifically for video, but you can insert rich content using OOXML - see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b32c262c-8945-47dd-ac69-4842443d3307/embedding-videos-in-the-document?forum=appsforoffice

Comment: Thanks for the help... I tried this and it work up to some extent but not fully.... When I'm trying to add ooxml, it gives error... take a look at this...
@http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594009/is-this-correct-open-office-xml